# How to loop through an array from XLookup to return a specific value in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I'm working on a custom function and so far I was able to run a Xlookup within it in VBA. Now I want to return a specific array value from the xlookup based on certain criteria. I'm stuck on how to actually do this.

The condition I want is if the array value does not equal 0, it will return that value. Otherwise, it will keep checking the other values.

Here is what I have so far. It also included my various attempts of trying to do it.

```
Function SWFQReport(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates)
    date_array_lookup = Application.XLookup(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates, "NONE", 0)
    date_array = Array(date_array_lookup)

    'Dim order_date As String'
    'Dim i As Interger'
    'For i = 2 To 3'
        'If date_array(i) <> 0 Then order_date = i '
        'Else: order_date = 0'
    
    'Dim order_date As Variant'
    'Debug.Print date_array_lookup'
    
    'If date_array(1) <> 0 Then'
        'order_date = date_array(1)'
    'Else'
        'order_date = "TEST"'
    'End If'

    SWFQReport = date_array
End Function
```

Comment: Difficult to guess without knowing what arguments you're passing in to that function.  If `date_array_lookup` is already an array though, there's no need to wrap it in `Array()`

Comment: If `sales_order_lookup` is >1 cell then the return value from XLookup will be a 2D array (`sales_order_lookup` is a column) or a 1D array(`sales_order_lookup` is a row)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allen, there were a number of issues in your code. You did not provide an example of your data but based on your follow-on response, I took a best guess and created some sample data as follows:

[image]

I then reworked the code. The line `date_array = Array(date_array_lookup)` was redundant because `date_array_lookup` is already a multi-dimensional array. Converting it again only confused the issue. SWFQReport should be declared as a variant because it can return either a date or string value. You will also need to tweak the `For ... Next` loop. The new function starts at column 1 instead of column 2 which you originally had:

```
Function SWFQReport(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    On Error Resume Next

    SWFQReport = 0

    date_array_lookup = Application.XLookup(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates, "NONE", 0)

    ' Test if we found anything. If not, Ubound will throw an error
    ' because the returned data is a variant string (Value=NONE) and not an array.
    If UBound(date_array_lookup) = 0 Then
        SWFQReport = "NONE"
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Find first non-zero date and return that
    For i = 1 To 3
        If date_array_lookup(1, i) <> 0 Then
            SWFQReport = date_array_lookup(1, i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Based on my sample data, I created another function to test the result:

```
Function fTest()

    Cells(1, 6) = SWFQReport("A0002", Range("A1:A5"), Range("B1:D5"))
    
End Function
```

Set this up in a test workbook and have a play with it. To see what is going on, in the VB editor position your cursor inside the fTest function and press F8 to begin stepping through the code. You should also open the Locals Window (View -> Locals Window) which will let you inspect the contents of all variables.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will return the first non-zero value or zero if no values are found. You run it as follows:

```
varDateValue = SWFQReport(Param1, Param2, Param3)
If varDateValue <> 0 Then
   ... Do something
End If
```

Code for function SWFQReport. Note the Variant declaration is something I put there for completeness only. You should replace it with the correct data type declaration, probably `As Date`:

```
Function SWFQReport(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates) As Variant

    Dim i As Integer

    SWFQReport = 0

    date_array_lookup = Application.XLookup(sales_order_lookup, sales_order_column, order_dates, "NONE", 0)
    date_array = Array(date_array_lookup)

    For i = 2 To 3
        If date_array(i) <> 0 Then 
            SWFQReport = date_array(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I followed your code exactly, using As Variant and As Date but I'm still getting error. I'm getting the #VALUE! error so maybe the issue is the arguments?

sales_order_lookup = an order number such as G2582, recognized as text in the spreadsheet

sales_order_column = column containing order numbers (ex. C:C) and the column heading

order_dates = array of dates (ex. D:F) recognized as a number in the spreadsheet and including the column heading

Do any of these need an As String, or As Integer, or something?

Comment: See my second answer below.